# get list of all members with specific role discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

i want the bot send all member with role named weed but intead it send only bot name

my code:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def mom(self,ctx, *args):
        server = ctx.message.guild
        role_name = (' '.join(args))
        role_id = server.roles[0]
        for role in server.roles:
            if role_name == role.name:
                role_id = role
                break
        else:
            await ctx.send("Role doesn't exist")
            return
        for member in server.members:
            if role_id in member.roles:
                await ctx.send(f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}")
```

Comment: Ideally add which imports you have to use so somebody else could run this code. You could edit your question so it's more clear for others

Comment: please post complete code and adjust identation

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `role.members`

```py
@commands.command()            # ↓ This will make sure that the argument passed is a discord.Role object
async def mom(self, ctx, role: discord.Role):
    members = role.members
    for member in members:
        await ctx.send(f'{member.display_name} - {member.id}')
```

Reference:

- [Role.members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20members#discord.Role.members)

Comment: it still send only the bot name . i think it should be a parametre for members type( btw m working with cogs )

Comment: do you have intents.members enabled?

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is something called `role.members` which returns all the members with the role "role". Here is an example of the code:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mom(self,ctx, *args):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    role_name = (' '.join(args))
    role_id = server.roles[0]
    for role in server.roles:
        if role_name == role.name:
            role_id = role
            break
        else:
            await ctx.send("Role doesn't exist")
            return
    for member in role.members:
        await ctx.send(f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}")
```

Try to replace your command with this one.